# Why isn't it possible to switch over class objects?

Tags: java, switch-statement

What would be the best way to switch over class-literals?
[Every class-instance exists only once and is an immutable constant](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html) but still, this seems to be not supported:

```
static void switchOnClass(Class<?> cls) {
    switch (cls) {
    case String.class -> System.out.println("String class");
    case Integer.class -> System.out.println("Integer class");
    default -> System.out.println("Unknown");
    }
}
```

Comment: What you want seems to be very similar to this preview/future feature of Java, except that that's for switching depending on the instance of an object, not on an actual Class: https://openjdk.org/jeps/427

Comment: I know about pattern matching. I use it every day. Its wonderful. In fact, this jep inspired the question a bit.

Comment: Is this purely a "why is that so?" question, or do you have a particular usecase in mind where this (or something similar) would be useful?

Comment: Well ... if you know about the JEP, then surely the answer your question is self evident.  It isn't allowed because the JLS doesn't allow it.  Why not?  Presumably because nobody has been sufficiently motivated to support it.

Comment: A factory method that uses classes as identifiers.

Comment: I did wonder if I just didn't get the syntax right, as I was sure that this use-case was highly common and I just have overlooked something obvious. I guess the question is a poorly phrased in that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer my own question:
The use case seems to be not common enough, that this feature is supported. Currently (as of Java 18) a switch-case-statement supports switching over literals:

- primitive types
- their wrapper classes
- enum constants
- String literals

It can utilize (exhaustive) pattern-matching like the instanceof operator, and as of Java 19 it will support [record-pattern-matching](https://openjdk.org/jeps/405) which will maybe get extended by the following:

> Future Work
>
> There are many directions in which the record patterns described here
> could be extended:
>
> - Array patterns, whose subpatterns match individual array elements;
> - Varargs patterns, when the record is a varargs record;
> - Inference for type arguments in generic record patterns, possibly using a diamond form (<>);
> - Do-not-care patterns, which can appear as an element in a record component pattern list but do not declare a pattern variable; and
> - Patterns based upon arbitrary classes rather than only record classes.

But currently it seems the best way to switch over classes would be, like @Davide pointed out, to use a uniquely identifieable, human-readable attribute, like their name/path. Which in itself would be restricted by anonymous, hidden, and local classes.

Answer (score 1):

There are two answers:

1. Because nobody on the Java team has been sufficiently motivated to propose `switch` for a broader range of types.  (Use-cases are uncommon ...)
2. Because there is a significant technical issue ...

The thing is that a `switch` statement needs the values in the cases to be *compile time* constant expressions.  This is necessary because the compiler has to be able to check that the values in different cases are distinct.  We can't have something like this:

```
int A = 1;
int B = 1;
switch (foo) {
    case A:  doSomething(); break;
    case B:  doSomethingElse(); break;
}
```

The compile time checks work for integer and String values (that are results of constant expressions) and enum names because these types have models of equality<sup>1</sup> that will give the same answer at compile time and runtime.

Unfortunately, this doesn't generalize to other reference types:

- On the one hand, `==` would most likely be too difficult to use in practice.
- On the other hand, it would not be possible for the compiler to perform a *compile time* check that the case values are pair-wise not `equals` to each other.

Even class literals (e.g. `Foo.class`) are problematic<sup>2</sup>.  It turns out that if the same class is loaded by two different class loaders, you can get two distinct `Class` objects.  And they are NOT equal according to either `==` or `equals`.  They could probably come up with a semantic that was amenable to a compile time check.  But the runtime semantics would have a nasty gotcha in the above scenario.

---

<sup>1 - Note that the equality model for `switch` statements /expressions using `String` is `equals`, not `==`.

2 - I don't know if the Java language designers actually considered supporting `switch` for `Class` values, but I can understand why they haven't done it yet.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible because is not part of the language.

As explained [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html) on the oracle documentation:

> **A `switch` works with the `byte`, `short`, `char`, and `int` primitive data types**. It also works **with enumerated types** (discussed in Enum Types), **the String class**, and a few special **classes that wrap certain primitive types: Character, Byte, Short, and Integer** (discussed in Numbers and Strings).

Java is evolving through the years. The old versionsthe  of switch doesn't allow to use the `String` as parameter of the switch. May be thatin a newer version of java this functionality will be added, but for what I know at the moment it is not planned.

---

If you plan to use classes as business object of the switch you can use their full names and use the switch over strings

```
 switch (myObject.getClass().getCanonicalName()) {
     case "myFullClassName": ...
     case "myOtherFullClassName": ...

 }
```

Comment: Since Java 17 its even possible to use it like instanceof and in newer versions you can even add boolean expressions, so I'm wondering why classes (which even have their own literals) are not supported. I can see many use cases for this, and wonder if the best alternative would be to just use chained if/else-blocks.

Comment: You could use the class name and use it as switch with a string if you like. Please see the updated answer

Comment: That `switch` won't work, the cases need to be compile-time constants.

Comment: The cases are compile time constants. The switch is variable, but cases are constants.

Comment: A method-call is allways during runtime

Comment: You are right @StephenC I updated the code to be usable in that case.

Comment: @rzwitserloot Actually, the question is explicitly _not_ about pattern matching (as in JEP 427, switch to check 'instanceof' an object), see comments thread. And this answer at no point says that String in switch is "new", just that what's possible in switch changed over the years and might change again.

Comment: It should be the last page of oracle. Is not my fault if they don't update everyhing at every new java version. In any case, this works for older versions and clearly expose that for a language design not all classes can be supported in the switch case statement